# PyTorch - TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0

Tags: pytorch, typeerror, image-segmentation

I was doing a unet++ (nested unet) with PyTorch, but I got the error `TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.`
But I'm still not sure what causes the error.

```
  File "train.py", line 354, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 314, in main
    train_log = train(config, train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer)
  File "train.py", line 111, in train
    for input, target, _ in train_loader:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1203, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1229, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 425, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 287, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/content/Nested-UNet/dataset.py", line 63, in __getitem__
    img_id + self.mask_ext), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)[..., None])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Seems like the directory is alright, not sure why this happens.
Here's the code: https://github.com/Sax-Ted/Nested-UNet .
Can anyone help me with finding the issue or give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: Based on the error, one of the images is missing: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`